# .htaccess error on local site in docksal

Tags: 8, .htaccess

I've built a Drupal 8.6.4 website within Acquia Dev Desktop, but moved it into a local Docker/Docksal setup to continue working (haven't used it before) - on a mac, if it matters. Everything seems fine, but for two issues. The first is a bunch of Security warnings in the logs about htaccess, saying to add an htaccess containing some specific code to the "/var/www/config/default" directory, but I don't have this file directory. It's a Docksal set-up: just ~/projects/projectname/docroot set-up on my computer.

The second issue, which I suspect may be related, is that I can't Drush archive-backup --destination=x/x/x.. It always tells me the file permission prevents it, Even if I give full read/write permission on the folder. But I can do it without the --destination added. It just puts it in a temp folder.

Here's the Error I see - it generates most any time I load an admin page.

```
    Security warning: Couldn't write .htaccess file. Please create a .htaccess file in your /var/www/config/default directory which contains the following lines:
    # Deny all requests from Apache 2.4+.
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
      Require all denied
    </IfModule>

    # Deny all requests from Apache 2.0-2.2.
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
      Deny from all
    </IfModule>

    # Turn off all options we don't need.
    Options -Indexes -ExecCGI -Includes -MultiViews

    # Set the catch-all handler to prevent scripts from being executed.
    SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
    <Files *>
      # Override the handler again if we're run later in the evaluation list.
      SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2013_003
    </Files>

    # If we know how to do it safely, disable the PHP engine entirely.
    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
      php_flag engine off
    </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a directory in the root of the Acquia project, `config/default`.So, all you need it's make it writable.

or you can  change `$config_directories['vcs']` and `$config_directories['sync']` in your `settings.php` to somewhere which will be writable .

Comment: This is no longer in an Acquia project. The second option looks easy enough - I'm just not quite sure what I'm looking at. I don't have anything matching what you have above.  The closest I have is `$config_directories = array(CONFIG_SYNC_DIRECTORY => dirname($app_root) . '/config/' . basename($site_path),);` ... Not quite the same, but I created a "sync" folder just above the docroot, and changed this code's /config/ to "../sync". Only been a few minutes, but errors haven't appeared yet. So... maybe I did the right thing? Merci!

Comment: Dang.. Error is back. that didn't solve it.

Comment: @turpentyne

>This is no longer in an Acquia project. !!!
are you  sure about this because I'm working on a project nowdays that I'm use that folder for syncing  Configuration on Environments, 

I have `$config_directories['vcs'] = $app_root . '/../config/default';` on my local.settings.php you can test it.